# JPQL to select objects with tags and categories

Tags: jpql

The simplified design of the db schema is something like this:
    Document (did)
    Category (cid)
    Tag (tid, cid) // a tag belongs to a category
    DocumentTag(did, tid) // a document may have one or more tags, a tag may be assigned to more than one documents

Now given a list of tags, I want to select documents belonging to any of the tags within in the same category, and belonging to all categories defined by the tags.

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? With the little information you've provided, it's hard to tell exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: @DannyMo eventually i did it by using java instead of jpql